# reStructured Text - Escape a headline?

Tags: restructuredtext, text-formatting

I have a reStructuredText document. rST uses `=====`, etc. as a heading format.

However I need to include some lines that have this text in it, e.g.:

```
some of my text
=====
stuff
=====
some more of my text
```

And I don't want the `====` to be interpreted as a heading, i.e. I don't want `stuff` to be a heading. I would rather that those equal signs are just displayed as is.

Is this possible in rST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The escape character in reStructuredText is `\`:

```
some of my text
\=====
stuff
=====
some more of my text
```

Will be rendered as:

```
some of my text ===== stuff ===== some more of my text
```